# Overwriting values in input fields in React after being passed via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I seem to be confusing myself, I am passing props into another component so I can populate form data. Think of opening a form so I can edit a contact.

This is one of the fields

```js
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={props.firstname}
                  placeholder={props.firstname}
                  onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                  className="w-full border-b px-4 py-2"
                />
```

When the form opens the value is of course the `props.firstname` but I am unable to over write it. Is this because a value can only be sent and not over written?

I am trying to have component populated with a contacts information, but then have the values editted to be sent to another end point to update said contact.

Am i missing something? This the last bit of my app i need to finish

Comment: I think you need to pass a callback function to this component where the function will change the firstname value when invoked

Comment: If you have code on github could you please provide the link?

Comment: do you mean `onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}` ?https://github.com/mrpbennett/contact_fastapi/blob/react-fe/frontend/src/components/editContact.jsx

Comment: try this
```let  [firstName,  setFirstName]  =  useState(props.firstName);```
and 
```js
<input
type="text"
value={firstName}
placeholder={firstName}
onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
className="w-full border-b px-4 py-2"
/>
```

Comment: let me know if it solves

Comment: Thank you Sir! That helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why people provide answers in the comments and not as an answer. [Arihant Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14517622/arihant-jain)'s answer:

```
let  [firstName,  setFirstName]  =  useState(props.firstName);

<input 
  type="text" 
  value={firstName}
  placeholder={firstName}
  onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
  className="w-full border-b px-4 py-2"
/>
```